# Weird behaviour in HTA application with 'label' tag

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

So, here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Function obtn1()
    document.forms("form").btn1.style.display = "none"
    document.forms("form").btn2.style.display = "block"
    msgbox "btn1"
End Function

Function obtn2()
    document.forms("form").btn1.style.display = "block"
    document.forms("form").btn2.style.display = "none"
    msgbox "btn2"
End Function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    <label>
        <input type="button" value="btn1" onclick="obtn1()" name="btn1" style="display: block;" />
        <input type="button" value="btn2" onclick="obtn2()" name="btn2" style="display: none;" />
    </label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Its function is very simple: Display the first button. When this button is clicked, show a second button and hide the first button. When the second button is clicked, show the first button and hide the second button.

But I couldn't make it work. However if I remove the `<label>` element or set the attribute `for="somethinghere"` then the code works just fine.

So can anybody tell me what have I done wrong? I'm running on Windows 7 x86 with Internet Explorer 10 installed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "couldn't make it work"? What happens? Also, why do you need the label? If taking it out makes the code work, why leave it in?

Comment: Just read the Definition and usage of label http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: So it may click on both of your inputs if you wrap the label like your code

Comment: Ah, so because this `label` tag doesn't have a specified form element to bound to, then when I click on it, it triggers both buttons. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark is as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as **R Lam** said above, as the `label` tag doesn't have a specified form element to bound to (the `for` attribute), when the user clicks on it, it triggers both `input[type="button"]` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `input` tags in different `label` tags like this:

```
<form id="form">
    <label>
        <input type="button" value="btn1" onclick="obtn1()" name="btn1" style="display: block;" />
    </label>    
    <label>
        <input type="button" value="btn2" onclick="obtn2()" name="btn2" style="display: none;" />
    </label>
</form>
```